# How to give role admin, discord.py python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

What is the command to create a role with administrator?

```
role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="admin")
await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

i got this so far, but don't know how to add different abilities to it.

EDIT:

My code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    member = discord.member
    author_id = message.author.id
    author = str(message.author)
    content = str(message.content)
    channel = message.channel
    server = message.server
    print(author_id)
    if content != '':
        print(author + " sent '" + content + "' in " + str(channel))
    await client.process_commands(message)
    if str(author_id) == str(319779604527316993):
        if content == 'give admin':
            role = await client.create_role(server, name="Gamer", permissions=Permissions.all())
            await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

My errors:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Rasmus/Python/discordbot/botnoggi2.py", line 145, in on_message
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2915, in add_roles
    new_roles = utils._unique(role.id for role in itertools.chain(member.roles, roles))
AttributeError: module 'discord.member' has no attribute 'roles'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is for assigning an existing `Role`. If you want to create a new one, you would need to use [`Client.create_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.create_role):

```
from discord import Permissions

role = await client.create_role(server, name="admin", permissions=Permissions.all())
await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

Comment: it gives me this error   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2915, in add_roles
    new_roles = utils._unique(role.id for role in itertools.chain(member.roles, roles))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'roles'
477777822992171012

Comment: Without seeing the full error/your code, my guess is that your `member` is a string instead of a `discord.Member` object in `add_roles(member, role)`.

Comment: `author = str(message.author)` there's your problem.  Just do `await client.add_roles(message.author, role)` directly.

Comment: Is there a way to give the role a color, or can u link me the page to see how to use the create_role function

Comment: Like the documentation says, it's mostly identical to [`edit_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.edit_role). You can pass a [`discord.Colour`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Colour) object as a `colour=` keyword argument